# Is my code correct?

Tags: wp-query, query

Can any one tell me about the following code.

This code is not giving error but not working.

```
$args = array(
    'cache_results' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,

    'post_type' => 'estate_property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $pagination,
    'posts_per_page' => $prop_no,
    'meta_key' => $meta_order,
    'orderby' => $order_by,
    'order' => $meta_directions,
    //'meta_query'      => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $categ_array,
        $action_array,
        $city_array,
        $area_array,
        $county_array

    )
);


$features = array();
$features = wpestate_add_feature_to_search_ajax();
$metas = wpestate_convert_meta_to_postin($meta_query);


if (!empty($features)) {
    if (!empty($metas)) {
        $all_ids = array_intersect($metas, $features);
    } else {
        $all_ids = $features;
    }
} else {
    $all_ids = $metas;
}


if (empty($all_ids)) {
    $all_ids[] = 0;
}


$args['post__in'] = $all_ids;


global $keyword;
$keyword = esc_html($_POST['keyword']);

if (!is_numeric($keyword)) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'taken-by',
            'meta_value' => $keyword,
            'type' => 'CHAR',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'),
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'property-project',
            'meta_value' => $keyword,
            'type' => 'CHAR',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'post_title',
            'value' => $keyword,
            'type' => 'CHAR',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );
} else {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ID',
            'value' => $keyword,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    );
}

/*if( !empty($keyword)  ){
 add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpestate_title_filter', 10, 2 );
}*/

$prop_selection = new Wp_Query($args);
```

Comment: The one thing that jumps out at me is that it's `WP_Query`, not `Wp_Query`. (Also, I have no idea what the `wpestate_*` functions do.)

Comment: WP_Query is also giving the same null result.